# Generating all rotationally invariant linear differential operators

Tags: differential-operators

It is relatively easy to show that the Laplacian

$$
\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}
$$

Is the unique second order linear differential operator that is invariant under rotations in the sense that

$$
\Delta (f(R\mathbf{x})) = (\Delta f)(R\mathbf{x}).
$$

The way I remember proving this was to write down a general

$$
D = \sum_i a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} + \sum_{ij} b_{ij} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j},
$$

and then demand the invariance property. A multiple of the Laplacian will then fall out.

I am wondering if there is a way to general all such operators (up to a certain degree). Are they all powers of the Laplacian? What happens for the vector Laplacian?

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong: there are many more such rotationally order 2 invariant operators, even modulo first order operators. For example, consider $r^2\Delta$. Were you thinking of *constant coefficient* differential operators? If so, then the first fundamental theorem of invariant theory for the orthogonal group ${\rm O}_n$ shows that indeed every constant coefficient differential operator on $K^n$ ($K$ a field) is a polynomial in $\Delta$. There is an analogous description, due to Roger Howe, for the case of ${\rm O}_n$-invariant polynomial coefficient differential operators.

Answer (score 5):

They are not all powers of the Laplacian.  For example, if a function $g$ is invariant under rotation, then the 0th order differential operator $D_g(f) = g f$ is invariant under rotation.  There is also the (first-order) radial derivative operator
$$
R(f) = xf_x + yf_y\,.
$$
Any (non-commutative) polynomial in $D_g$, $R$ and $\Delta$ will be a rotationally invariant differential operator, but these are not independent.  For example, we have the identity
$$
\left[\Delta, D_{x^2+y^2}\right] = D_4 + 4R,
$$
so $R$ is already in the ring generated by $\Delta$ and the $D_g$ where $g$ varies through rotationally invariant functions.

**Added comment:**  Of course, I should have mentioned the *other* first order linear rotationally invariant operator, the angular derivative operator:
$$
A(f) = x\,f_y - y\,f_x\,,
$$
with the identity
$$
R^2 + A^2 = D_{x^2+y^2}\,\Delta
$$

Answer (score 3):

Polynomials in the Laplacian are invariant under all isometries, not just rotations. This characterizes them by e.g. Helgason ([1959](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=117681), Thm 11) $=$ ([1962](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=145455), Prop. X.2.10) $=$ ([1984](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=754767), Prop. II.4.11), or Folland ([1995](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1357411), Thm [2.1](//books.google.com/books?id=puM9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA67)).

Answer (score 0):

More a comment than an answer - since $\nabla $ transforms as a vector, you could construct scalars by contracting an arbitrary number (say $n$) of $\nabla $s with an arbitrary rank-$n$ tensor. So it seems that to generate all operators in question, you'd at least have to generate all tensors on your underlying space (which implicitly seems to be 2-dimensional?). You'd discard some, such as antisymmetric of rank greater than 2, since the contraction would vanish, but it still seems there is a large number of possibilities. Perhaps some irreducibility specification is needed to make the question sharper?